# The GPU overheats and the laptop shuts down

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, gpu, overheating

I had to replace my laptop's graphics card a few weeks ago. I also had it cleaned. At first it was fine, except the fan was loud. But since yesterday it has shut down twice. Once when I tried to play the sims 3 and once when I was watching an hour-long video on youtube. I've been monitoring the GPU temp for a few hours. It's always at ~70 degrees and if I start the sims, it goes above 90 right away.

I can't take it to be repaired until the end of June because I'm in the middle of finals and I can't do anything without my laptop. I'm hoping that it's just the thermal paste but I'd like to know what else it could be and if it can wait until the end of June, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Laptops generally don't have graphics cards but instead have a GPU soldered to their motherboard. Most likely, your entire motherboard was replaced. And there's a lot of things that can go wrong in that process. Was it replaced by a professional?

Comment: He's not exactly a professional... He can repair laptops but it's not his main job, so to speak. My dad took it to him because they're friends, although I strictly told him not to.

We don't use the word gpu in my native language and I used it by mistake. He definitely didn't change the motherboard. He told me so and I only payed about a quarter of what it would cost.

Comment: If the fan is unusually loud, that suggests that the heat sink is not properly mated to the CPU or GPU. It could just be poor thermal paste application, but there are a lot of other things you can do wrong with a laptop's cooling system. You could, for example, bend the heat pipe, tighten the screws in the wrong order, or about a dozen other things. Laptops are much touchier than desktops. (Why did you have to replace the graphics card? Who determined that the graphics card was the problem? Are you *sure* your laptop *has* a graphics card that can be separately replaced?)

Comment: He said that dust got sucked into it and fried it. I think it happened when I vacuumed it. The fan is as loud as it was before I cleaned it. The problem is mostly that it's constantly running. I was worried over the thermal paste since the moment I found out where it was for some reason. That and I want it to be something easy to fix. My laptop has a dedicated graphics card or at least that's what I was told when I purchased it.

Comment: Most likely, you are confusing a dedicated graphics chip with a graphics card. What model laptop is it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply, my internet was down. It's an HP G62. It dpesn't have a dedicated graphics card (that's what we call it in greek, I don't know how to say it in english) and the processor is worse than I was told. I took it to someone who replaced the thermal pad. Now it's at ~67 idle and 90+ while gaming, which is normal for my laptop but apparently it's still too high. He said that I shouldn't spend money on it and it won't even last 2 months, which I don't understand. Unless he meant that the gpu temp will keep rising, it will shut down all the time and it will be essentially useless?

Comment: It's perfectly fine and normal for the GPU and CPU to run hot in a laptop. What's not normal is for the laptop to shut down during normal use.